# s3 filename is not changed after a successful filepicker.io upload

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker.io, filepicker

if I want to modify the filename on S3 storage, first i need to call the filepicker.pick then filepicker.store . File is then uploaded but filename is not changed as I have specify in store function.  Any idea why this is not done?

```
   filepicker.pick
     maxfiles: 1
     maxSize: 20*1024*1024
     mimetypes: ['image/*','document/*','text/*','application/pdf']
     language: Translation.language()
     services: ["COMPUTER","DROPBOX","URL","EVERNOTE","GOOGLE_DRIVE","SKYDRIVE"]
  , (blob) ->
     $(t.$('.filename')).val(blob.filename)
     $(t.$('.awskey')).val(blob.key)
     oldBlob=blob
     filepicker.store blob,
        location: 'S3'
        path: "/"
        container: 'bepisupportdocs.bepi-intl.org'
        filename:blob.key.split('_')[1],
        (new_blob) ->
           filepicker.remove oldBlob
           console.log JSON.stringify new_blob if debugThis
  , Fp.uploadError
```

Answer (score 0):

What is blob.key.split('_')[1] returning? Filename needs to be in single quotes per Filestack documentation: https://www.filestack.com/docs/file-ingestion/javascript-api/store

{filename: 'MyCoolPhoto.png'}

Comment: I traced down the option parameter , filename is double quoted:  `  {location: "S3", path: "/", container: "bepisupportdocs.bepi-intl.org", filename: "OZ.pdf"} `    As the file is uploaded in the given location , i think double quote will work . But  filename appears as   '<prefix>_OZ.pdf' and  not like 'OZ.pdf' .

Answer (score 0):

OK I have figured out. Filename should be integrated in path field of options and not in a seperate field. Code should be like below :

```
filepicker.pick
 maxfiles: 1
 maxSize: 20*1024*1024
 mimetypes: ['image/*','document/*','text/*','application/pdf']
 language: Translation.language()
 services: ["COMPUTER","DROPBOX","URL","EVERNOTE","GOOGLE_DRIVE","SKYDRIVE"]
 , (blob) ->
 $(t.$('.filename')).val(blob.filename)
 $(t.$('.awskey')).val(blob.key)
 oldBlob=blob
 filepicker.store blob,
    location: 'S3'
    path: "/"+blob.filename
    container: 'bepisupportdocs.bepi-intl.org',
    (new_blob) ->
       filepicker.remove oldBlob
       console.log JSON.stringify new_blob if debugThis
```

, Fp.uploadError